# How to avoid DeadlineExceededError errors with RPC

Tags: google-app-engine

I am getting the DeadlineExceededError with the Google App Engine.

Read this https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors I believe that it is due to:

google.appengine.runtime.apiproxy_errors.DeadlineExceededError: raised if an RPC exceeded its deadline. This is typically 5 seconds, but it is settable for some APIs using the 'deadline' option.

However, I can't find how to set the deadline option.  How do I do it?  I can only find examples of how to set the deadline for url_fetch, not the apiproxy_errors.

Adding more details:

I am using Python. An example of my usage is:

```
taskqueue.add( url='/hl', deadline=60)
```

So after I add to the taskqueue, the page at xyz.appspot.com/hl will be called, but it gave me the deadline exceeded error after 5 seconds.

Comment: What language are you using? Are you using datastore, memcache, task-queue, or something else?

Comment: In python, you can set the deadline with a little tricks into the appengine libraries itself.
How do you call APIs ? And which APIs in which language ?